# How to constrain the navigation bar and prevent it from moving

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I am creating NSDate objects, and I have a navigation bar that I am trying to maintain in a static position at the top of the screen. 
I want my NSDate objects to be created underneath the navigation bar, but they are being created above the navigation bar and push the navigation bar down.

[image: Before adding date elements]
[image: After adding date elements]

This is my insertNewObject function

```
- (void)insertNewObject
{
if (!_objects) {
    _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
[_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

I suspect it has to do with this function which calls the insertNewObject method. Specifically I believe that the self call means that it is telling it to create it at the top of the ViewController.

```
- (IBAction)addData:(id)sender {
// call insertNewObject
[self insertNewObject];
}
```

How can I constrain my navigation bar and prevent the new NSDate objects from being created above the navigation bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a navigation bar (not a navigation controller), then you need to use a UIViewController rather than a UITableViewController. A UITableViewController's view is the table view, so anything you add to the view becomes a subview of the table. With a UIViewController, you can add the navigation bar at the top, then add the table view underneath. You'll have to add an IBOutlet for the table view, and make the controller the data source and delegate for your table (those things are automatic when you use a UITableViewController).

The alternative, of course, is to just embed your UITableViewController in a navigation controller.